# Convenient way to reverse push button logic

Tags: switches, button

I'm building a LED flashlight powered by a 3.7v lithium battery that must be `ON` when I push the button `OFF` when the button is released.

**Problem**

The only push button that I have in stock works other way round: by default is always `ON` (the circuit between its 2 poles is connected) and when I push it interrupts the circuit entering in `OFF` mode.

What is the proper way to reverse its logic to the desired (`ON` when I push, `OFF` when I release)?

Comment: What does "convenient" mean to you? What are the voltage and current levels? How much room do you have for extra circuitry? How much standby current can you tolerate when the flashlight is off?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson With convenient I mean, without overcomplicating the project with too much circuitry or expensive components. I'm not sure about eventual standby current leakage tolerance, I can do some test anyway keeping it lower possible is better.

Comment: OK, what do you mean by "overcomplicating", "too much circuitry", or "expensive"? We can not read your mind, and these words have vastly different meanings to different people.

Comment: Easiest by far is probably to attach a small relay. Though you could of course also use a transistor. The mechanical solution will likely be far more important than the electrical solution.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I haven't a fixed budget or fixed mm size but since we are talking about a flashlight project, you already have an hint about what would be reasonable or unreasonable. And if you propose the cheapest possible solution to achieve the purpose you cannot go wrong.

Comment: The cheapest possible solution is almost certainly to buy the correct switch. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Your answers don't make sense.The point of having a forum where ask questions if to learn how to do something. Otherwise you could answer "buy everything in the store" for near all questions. What is the sense of these answers? If you don't know how to answer just avoid to reply rather than useless comments, you have commented 3 times here to say nothing useful to no one.

Comment: are you certain that your switch is a SPST?

Comment: yes, the switch is SPST. sorry if I seemed grumpy but this answer has been downvoted and I don't understand what is the problem. That is more easy just using a switch that works without need of workarounds was obvious in first stance.

Comment: The problem with this question is that you haven't given us any concrete specifications. You seem willing to add components to the flashlight but reject the idea of just buying the correct switch. It is very difficult for us to figure out what your constraints and reasoning really are. I'm not going to waste time writing an answer if you can't give us a clear idea of what you want and why.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson What is the purpose is clear:  learn how to reverse the logic of this kind of button, in the use case explained, and "use another button" negate the purpose of the question itself. I have given all elements to allow you to suggest what is better to do. What other constraint do you need exactly? An user has already proposed a solution but it has some problematic exposed in the comments. Can you provide a better solution?

Comment: **Why** will you not just buy the correct switch? What is your **reason** for rejecting this option? Do you really want to solve this problem quickly and easily or do you want to be presented with all possible ways of fixing the flashlight? Why can't you give us specific, quantifiable guidance for the maximum price and volume of the solution?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I have already on way lots of components and push to power switches too. I don't refuse to buy the right component and nothing prevents me too buy the whole flashlight as well. I want to know how I can achieve this to learn something new. You are free to decide by yourself the trade off between size, cost, and reliability considering the use case. What would you do if you have to manage the product engineering department of a facility that has tons of this kind of switches that can reuse, and there is shortage of others buttons with no possibility to restock in time?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work. The standby current draw is less than a microamp. Depending on the battery size, the battery might last almost as long as without a load.

"Jonk" loves these kinds of problems, he will likely have something better.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkJ3N6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: 10M you serious? If you get moisture anywhere remotely near that flashlight, it will go haywire. And lets not even mention EMC. Cough and the LED will flicker.

Comment: @Lundin - If this is a product, use the correct type of switch. If this is temporary hack, try this circuit.

Comment: Hack or not, it won't be a reliable one. I'd much rather take shorter battery life in exchange for an actually working flashlight, by picking 10k or so.

Comment: I once designed a <1 nano-amp trans-impedance amplifier with a 300M feedback resistor. Yes, it needed to be shielded very well and protected from moisture. Agree that protecting a flashlight from moisture may not be practical. But, this is not a practical question anyway.

Comment: I built the circuit, put it in a throwaway plastic food container. V1 = 3 AA Ni-MH batteries, M1 = ZVN4424A, R1 = 100 ohms, D1 = common white LED. Works fine. Can't get the LED to flicker, even if I put it near an AC power drill, or touch the circuit.

Comment: Try to put it next to an AC contactor toggling 10A or so. Or well, put it through formal conducted/radiated susceptibility testing at a lab, 30V/m and beyond. EMC aside, you could also try to put that enclosure outdoors, preferably in a geographic region with lots of moisture and rapid temperature changes over the day. There's just no way that this design will work, no amount of IP69 or PCB lacquer will save it in the long term. I speak out of experience, because we once had a product with nearly identical design and had to recall thousands of units.